# Is react setState a asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
   const INITIAL_STATE={
        selectedFile:[],
    }
```

State Initialization.

```
 onFileChange = event => { 
        // Update the state 
        
        this.setState({ selectedFile:this.state.selectedFile.concat([event.target.files[0]])  });         // console.log([event.target.name],"sdgad"
        console.log(this.state.selectedFile,"Yoo")
        
      };
```

This is used to update the state with a list of values the moment it is entered.

```
<input type="file" onChange={this.onFileChange} /> ------File-----<br/>
```

render method above.

Result after inputting two values-

[]-value 1

[file]-value 2

Comment: give us more code.

Comment: try : this.setState(state => { selectedFile:state.selectedFile.concat([event.target.files[0]])  });

Comment: We don't see how you initialize `this.state`.

Comment: setState is asynchoronusly, so if you try check state value directly after update you have access to previus value. you can pass as second parametr callback function witch will be called after state updating.

Comment: Seems like the problem is in your log rather than your logic. try `this.setState({ selectedFile:this.state.selectedFile.concat([event.target.files[0]])  },()=>{console.log([event.target.name])}); ` excuse the messi parentheses.

Comment: Thanks guys,seemed to be a console.log error.